# open a url in applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a applescript to get current album name in iTunes, and set to clipboard. How can I open a url ,for instance, to google the album name?

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set track_album to the album of the current track
    set the clipboard to track_album
end tell
```

Comment: See the answer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18487/where-did-url-access-scripting-app-go-in-lion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: `tell application "Safari" to search the web for track_album`

This will search using Safari's default search engine. If you want to do a custom search on a particular site, say, Last.fm, you can compose a search query like this:

```
set query to "http://www.last.fm/search?q=" & track_album & "&type=album"
tell application "Safari" to open location query
```